# Generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a method on a class in which I use a generic that is of type UIViewController and conforms to a protocol.  Yet when I call this public method from another class I am receiving "Generic parameter could not be inferred".  Not sure why as I've already told the method the generics type.

```
public func mapBlocks<T: UIViewController where T: MyProtocol>(mapper:(name: String, obj: T ) -> ()) {
   // do something
}
```

Error happens here when I try to call the method from another class...

```
MyClass.mapBlocks { (name, obj) -> () in 
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old and I really hope you solved the problem in the last one and a half years. ;-) But for everybody who stumbles over this question again here is the solution.

You need to pass the type of T to the generic method by explicitly defining the type of the closure parameters when calling the method. Here is the Swift3 example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
}

class MyClass: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
}

func mapBlocks<T: UIViewController>(mapper: @escaping (String, T) -> ()) where T: MyProtocol {
}

mapBlocks { (name: String, obj: MyClass) in
}
```

Hope this helps!